# How to subtract an element of an array from every element in another array in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, fortran

I have a 2D array called zeta_list containing 100 X and Y coordinate values. I also have another 2D array called X. Now I want to subtract the first X coordinate in the list from every element in the X array, and then carry this on to subtract till the nth X coordinate via a do loop in Fortran. However when I try to do this, I get Error: Inconsistent ranks for operator at (1) and (1). My code is as follows:

```
PROGRAM LensingTest1


DOUBLE PRECISION,DIMENSION(1,1000)::M_list
DOUBLE PRECISION,DIMENSION(100,100)::X,Y,z_m_z_x,z_m_z_y,dist_z_m_z, alpha_x, alpha_y
DOUBLE PRECISION,DIMENSION(2,1000)::zeta_list

open(9,file='/home/amruth/Desktop/Coding/Fortran/Test_Programs/Lensing_Test/zeta_list.txt')
open(8,file='/home/amruth/Desktop/Coding/Fortran/Test_Programs/Lensing_Test/X.txt')
read(9,*)zeta_list
read(8,*)X

write(*,*) X  - zeta_list(1,1:1)#this is the line that causes the error

!The do loop might then be 

!do i=1,size(M_list,1),1
    !z_m_z_x = X - zeta_list(1,i:i)
!end do


END PROGRAM LensingTest1
```

When I explicitly check the value for zeta_list(1,1:1), it is a single scalar value so I don't see why I should be getting this error as I can easily subtract any scalar values from an entire array such as X.

Comment: why not `zeta_list(1,i)` ?

Comment: In a hurry so no proper answer, but zeta_list(1,1:1) is NOT a scalar, it is an array with one element - all array sections are themselves arrays. This is not the same as zeta_list(1,1) which is a scalar.

Comment: aside it seems you migh use `sum` and dispense with the loop

Comment: @agentp ah at first I thought that zeta_list(1,i) would subtract the entire row/column and I kept thinking it was an array, in a pythonic way....This seems to work fine, how would you go about using sum to get rid of the loop? do you mean sum(zeta_list,DIM=2) ?

Comment: `z_m_z_x = X - sum(zeta_list(1,:))` should be equivalent to your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the comments allude to this well -- you're referencing a 1X1 array element which fortran does not understand as a scalar, though effectively it is. Agentp provides one option for confronting this,

```
    z_m_z_x = X - sum(zeta_list(1,:))
```

I usually do something similar, different really only in a semantic manner from agentp's suggestion

```
    z_m_z_x= X(i,1) - maxval(zetalist(1,:))
```

In each case you're transforming the array to a scalar via 1) summing all the elements in the array, which is only 1 or 2) picking the maxvalue of all the elements in the array, which again is the max of only 1 value. Minval would work equally well. However, if I understand your question right --- that you have a M x 2 array 'X' that you are trying to subtract out of the values from the first column of zeta_list ---

then there might be a way to vectorize this operation. If you were trying to subtract from X the values of the first column of a 2 X M array, and the arrays both had M rows, then you could simply

```
    X(:,1)=X(:,1) - zetalist(:,1)
    X(:,2)=X(:,2) - zetalist(:,1)
```

However, this approach will only work if the arrays are of the same number of rows- a specific range would require slicing to an equivalent number of rows in each array as well as the slicing to the right columns. If you are trying to subtract the 1,1 array element from every location in X and you want to use the loop then you could write

```
   DO i=1,M 
           X(i,1) = X(i,1)- zetalist(1,1)
           X(i,2) = X(i,2)- zetalist(1,1)
   end DO
```

Comment: this showed me a few different ways to go about doing it! thanks for the input, particularly the vectorization approach which is usually preferable to loops when considering speed